# Quotients of multivariate polynomial rings - is $k[x][y]/(y-x^2) \cong k[y][x]/(y-x^2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism

This question is motivated by exercise 1.1 in Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry. One has to prove that $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable. I know that this can be done by viewing $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ as the image under the surjection $k[x][y] \to k[x][y]/(y-x^2)$ given by $x \mapsto x$, $y \mapsto x^2$ (that is, $f(x,y) \mapsto f(x,x^2)$). Since $x^2 \in k[x]$, the image under this evaluation map is just $k[x]$.

My question is, why does it apparently not work to view $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ as $k[y][x]/(y-x^2)$, the image under the map $k[y][x] \to k[y][x]/(y-x^2)$ given by $x \mapsto \sqrt{y}$, $y \mapsto y$? Since $\sqrt{y} \notin k[y]$, I think the evaluation can't produce a ring isomorphic to $k[y]$. But it seems to me that if $k[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ is isomorphic to $k[x]$, then it should be isomorphic to $k[y]$ also, and therefore cannot be isomorphic to the ring obtained by this evaluation.

Comment: this is a good question, and there's quite a bit of subtlety here. for a few things to think about: if $f:R\to S$ is a ring isomorphism, and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $f(I)$ is an ideal of $S$, and the map $r+I\mapsto f(r)+f(I)$ induces an isomorphism $R\big/I\to S\big/f(I)$. so, to answer your title question, yes: those two rings are isomorphic

Comment: to address your second paragraph; for convenience, consider $k[x,y]$ as being a subring of the algebraic closure $F$ of the field $k(x,y)$; in particular, in this field $F$, we can unambigiously talk about an element $\sqrt{y}$ (up to sign). you are correct that $\sqrt{y}\notin k[y]$. however, this does *not* mean that $k[\sqrt{y}]$ cannot be isomorphic to $k[y]$, and in fact those two subrings of $F$ *are* isomorphic! can you see what a natural choice of isomorphism between them might be? the point is that two rings can be isomorphic without being equal

Comment: perhaps it is slightly more tractable to think about the subrings $\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{\pi}]$ of $\mathbb{C}$; these two rings are isomorphic, even though certainly $\sqrt{\pi}\notin\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom So the ring I get by $x \to \sqrt{y}$ and $y \to y$ is something like $k[y][\sqrt{y}]$, which is isomorphic to $k[\sqrt{y}]$, I think?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right :) ... and if you consider $k[y][\sqrt{y}]$ as a subring of the field $F$ I mention above, then in fact it is *equal* to $k[\sqrt{y}]$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom  and would the isomorphism $k[y] \to k[\sqrt{y}]$ just be $y \to \sqrt{y}$? Just out of curiosity, do you know how I could apply a similar idea to a more complicated quotient, say, $k[x,y]/(y^2+x+y)$? On one hand, $f(x,y) \to f(x,\frac{-x}{y+1})$ seems to imply this quotient is isomorphic to $k[x][\frac{-x}{y+1}]$, while $f(x,y) \to f(-y(y+1),y)$ implies it is isomorphic to $k[y][-y(y+1)]$. The latter seems isomorphic to $k[y]$ but I can't think of a way to show the former is isomorphic to $k[x]$. Maybe $y \to \frac{-x}{y+1}$ is not the right evaluation map?